# Windows 7 Windows Update shortcut in Start/All Programs missing (deleted)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, start-menu

I have deleted the Windows Update Shortcut found in the All Programs list.
I would like to reinstall it, but cannot seem to find the correct method.
Any assistance will be sincerely appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135246-start-menu-all-programs-windows-7-restore-default-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 2):

Go to this location:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

right click and select Create a shortcut to:
%windir%\system32\wuapp.exe startmenu

Name it:
Windows Update

right click on the shortcut and choose properties. go to the Shortcut tab and set the "Start in" to:
%windir%\system32

"Comment: to:
Delivers software updates and drivers, and provides automatic updating options.

finally click the "change Icon" button and it should default to this path:
%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll
but you'll have to select the icon manually.  For me the icon for windows update is the one in the 3rd row 12th column.

Once you have this shortcut made you can copy to other places if you want also.

Also I know that not all of this is required but if you want it to be an exact copy of the default one I put all the information for you here so do with it as you wish. :)

Comment: Lornecash, Brilliant! Just by following your instructions, I have learned much more  than I knew before (about Start Menus, Shortcuts, etc.) Thanks so much!  Ted